# How to give corner radius in one side to Imageview in swift?

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uiimage, rounded-corners, cornerradius

How can I give corner radius in one side to Imageview like zig zag?
like in image
[image]

In this image I want like a large image witch is **highlighted** in **Blue** line.

If anyone know about this Please help me.
And I apologize if I could not explane my problem properly.

Comment: [How to round only specific corners using maskedCorners](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/calayer/how-to-round-only-specific-corners-using-maskedcorners) might be start, or for something more complicated, something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34777992/how-to-create-unique-shapes-or-uiviews-in-swift) or [this](https://ayusinghi96.medium.com/draw-custom-shapes-and-views-with-uiberzierpath-ios-1737f5cb975)

Comment: This could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43623621/changing-the-shape-of-a-uiview-border

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve the problem using bezier path

Study the bezier path principle and find the appropriate control point

Here is the sample code

```
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height/3))

let path = UIBezierPath()
       
path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width, y: 0))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width, y: self.view.frame.size.height/3))
path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.size.height/3 - 50),
                            controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 200, y: self.view.frame.size.height/3 - 20),
                            controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width/2, y: self.view.frame.size.height/3 - 100))
path.close()

let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath

imageView.layer.mask = shapeLayer
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "spider.jpg")
self.view.addSubview(imageView)
```

[image]